# Exponential of Exponential

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

I am wondering if it's possible to express exp(exp(ix)) as a product of Trigonometric and Exponential function. Tried all manipulations to no avail.

Comment: The Euler-formula gives $\exp(ix)=\cos(x)+i\cdot \sin(x)$, so we have $\exp(\exp(ix))=e^{\cos(x)}\cdot (\cos(\sin(x)+i\cdot \sin(\sin(x)))$

Comment: This expression cannot be further simplified.

Answer (score 1):

I will just expand on what [Peter](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82961/peter) did. According to Euler's formula:

$$ e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\cdot \sin(x) $$

Applying that to your expression $exp(exp(ix))$ you'll get:

$$ e^{\exp(ix)}=e^{\cos(x)}\cdot e^{i\cdot sin(x)} $$

$$ e^{\exp(ix)}=e^{\cos(x)}\cdot (\cos(\sin(x))+i\cdot \sin(\sin(x))) $$